# how to change the progressive bar class from progress-bar-success to progress-bar-danger when the percentage is less than or equal to 50%

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js

I have a progressive bar when is working fine but the thing what I'm trying to achieve is if the percentage is below 50% I want the progressive bar to change to red colour from green colour. I'm working this in jQuery but not getting a result please can I get some assistance with this?

Thanks in advance

```
<td>
    <span class="header-text">
        <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success progress-bar-striped active progressbartextcolor" id="below50percent" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="25" aria-valuemin="0" v-bind:style="{width: customerLoan.progress + '%'}" aria-valuemax="100">{{customerLoan.progress || "0"}}%</div>
    </span>
</td>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var bars = 
        $('{{customerLoan.progress}}');
        for (i = 0; i < bars.length; i++) 
        {
            console.log(i);
            var progress = $(bars[i]).attr('{{customerLoan.progress}}');                             
            $(bars[i]).width(progress + '%');
            if (progress <= "50") 
            {                                            
                $(bars[i]).addClass("progress-bar-danger");
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure `$('{{customerLoan.progress}}');` doesn't do what you think it does, among other problems. I'm guessing your using some kind of plugin? The fact that you're using handle bars makes me think your also using some kind of templating engine? Angular maybe? We need a [mcve]. My guess is, you can't interact with this using jquery

Comment: Can't understand what {{customerLoan.progress}} is, the idea is simple here, based on the progress you just need to add/remove desired classes from element

Comment: {{customerLoan.progress}} specifies the width.

Comment: So why are you trying to use the width as a jquery selector? What are you expecting that to match? I'd suggest you read how jquery selectors work, because this isn't going to work at all https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SO. I would suggest you to not use jQuery for such kind of operations. Vue.js has built-in directive for it, called [v-bind:class][1]. All that you have to do, is to create computed object with all class requirements and then bind it to your progress bar. Here I have a working solution:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    customerLoan: {
      progress: 40
    }
  },
  methods: {},
  computed: {
    classObject: function() {
      return {
        'bg-success': this.customerLoan.progress >= 50,
        'bg-danger': this.customerLoan.progress < 50
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<table id="app">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span class="header-text">
                <div class="
                progress-bar  
                progress-bar-striped 
                active 
                progressbartextcolor" 
                id="below50percent" 
                role="progressbar" 
                aria-valuenow="25" 
                aria-valuemin="0" 
                aria-valuemax="100"
                v-bind:class='classObject'>
                    {{ customerLoan.progress }}%
                </div>
            </span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

You can manually change customerLoan.progress to ensure that class changes. Hope this will help you!
[1]: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html